# Cannot get documentid using pnp.sp.search in spfx app

Tags: sharepoint, spfx

In an older JavaScript app I used keyword-query to search for document properties, and I could add the 'DlcDocID' field (Document id) to be retrieved.

I am currently developing an Spfx version of the app, and use pnp.sp.search to get document data. This way I can get the UniqueId and the DocId, but not the Document Id. How can I have this parameter included in the search results?

Extra:

I am using 1.3.11, and this code

```
    pnp.sp.search(
      {
         Querytext:query,
         RowLimit:rows,
         StartRow:start,
         SelectProperties: ["DocId"
         , "UniqueId"
         ,"FileType"
         ,"ServerRedirectedEmbedURL"
         , "ServerRedirectedPreviewURL"
         ,"LastModifiedTime"
         ,"Write"
         ,"Size"
         ,"SPWebUrl"
         ,"ParentLink"
         ,"Title"
         ,"HitHighlightedSummary"
         ,"Path"
         ,"Author"
         ,"LastModifiedTime"
         ,"DlcDocID"
        ],
```

But DlcDocID is never retrieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the pnp
SearchResult interface didn't have the DlcDocID in this version. Adding it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looking [at the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/crawled-and-managed-properties-overview#managed-properties-added-in-sharepoint-server-2016), `DlcDocID` should be retrievable (it's queryable and retrievable by default). Have you tried using `SearchQueryBuilder` and `selectProperties`?

```
const q = SearchQueryBuilder().text(yourQuery).
    .rowLimit(10).processPersonalFavorites.selectProperties('*', 'DlcDocID');
const results = await sp.search(q);
```

[SearchQueryBuilder reference](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/search/#searchquerybuilder)

Comment: Is this only v2 (SearchQueryBuilder seems absent in v1) (see addition above)?